# How to interpolate Time series data using Linear interpolation on big datasets in Presto?

Tags: sql, pandas, interpolation, presto

I am dealing with large datasets using prestodb as query engine and Hive as meta-store with external storage linked. Below is the details of my scenario:

I have a dataset with time series data(timestamp) and a numeric column. I want to fill in missing values using interpolation techniques. For example
Input dataset:

[image]

[image]

After perfroming operation output should look like this:

[image][image]

One simpler solution is to use pandas and interpolate all values but loading millions of rows in memory is not a good way. Similarly presto does not support pagination.

What is the best way to achieve above scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can use `lag(ignore nulls)`/`lead(ignore nulls)` and some arithmetic for interpolation:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.pressure,
                (time_ms - prev_time_ms) * (next_pressure - prev_pressure) / (next_time_ms - prev_time_ms)
               ) as imputed_pressure
from (select t.*,
             to_milliseconds(time) as time_ms
             lag(pressure ignore nulls) over (order by time) as prev_pressure,
             lag(to_milliseconds(time)  ignore nulls) over (order by time) as prev_time_ms,
             lag(pressure ignore nulls) over (order by time) as next_pressure,
             lag(to_milliseconds(time)  ignore nulls) over (order by time) as next_time_ms
     from t
    ) t
```

Comment: I have tried above method by refining it further. Only issue I am facing is that IGNORE NULLS is not working for LEAD and LAG functions. Any workaround or solution for that?

Comment: Simple query like this is not working as well: 
SELECT lead(iws) IGNORE NULLS over () as next_iws FROM TSDS_104

Comment: @WAnjum . . . That is odd.  Presto says that it supports the option:  https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html.

Comment: Yes, I checked their documentation and it supports RESPECT, IGNORE NULLS but its not working for me. Looks like i need to create a ticket on git as well.

Comment: Issue was related to Presto version 0.231.